# Do Singer cycles create all matrices of maximal order in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am interested in elements of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of maximal order.  It is known that the maximum possible order of such an element is $q^n-1$ and that this bound is achievable via Singer cycles.  These are built in the following simple way.  Regard $V=\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and take a primitive element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.  Define the linear transformation $T_\alpha: V \to V$ by $T_\alpha(x)=\alpha x$.  It is then a simple matter to check that $T_\alpha$ represents an element of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$  of order $q^n-1$.

My question is:  do the Singer cycles create *all* the elements of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of order $q^n-1$.  That is, given such a matrix $A$, is there a way to find a primitive element $\alpha$ so that $A$ represents $T_\alpha$?  I have tried making use of the information gathered from the minimal polynomial of such a matrix $A$ (as it must divide $x^{q^n-1}-1$), but I do not see how to connect this to a suitable primitive in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.  This made me think that maybe it's just not true.  Any guidance and/or references are appreciated.

Added for context:  I am attempting to count the number of matrices $A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of maximal order $q^n-1$.  If these matrices are in one-to-one correspondence with the Singer cycles [who in turn correspond to primitives] then I am done.  In order to establish such a correspondence, I need the answer to this question to be in the affirmative when **one basis** is fixed for $V$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ for the whole of the argument.

Comment: This is a good question. I haven't thought it through, but I think this is true. After all, a linear transformation from $GL_n$ is a zero of it s characteristic polynomial by [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem). My first attack on proving this would be to try and show that the characteristic polynomial (obvious of the correct degree $n$) should be irreducible, when the order of the matrix is $q^n-1$.

Comment: Part of the issue, to confess, is my rustiness on the results on decompositions of an endomorphism and all the informative polynomial/canonical form business.

Comment: Actually, your question is likely to be a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1721645/11619). My vote to close it as such would be immediately binding, so I will wait for a little while so that interested parties can have their say.

Comment: I saw that question, but I didn't fully see the connection, mainly because of the third bulletpoint.

Comment: @Randall Doesn't the third bullet point mean that the answer to your question is "no", or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Randall, I think the third bullet point is simply about not all matrices of order $q^n-1$ being conjugate. After all, the conjugate matrices share the same minimal polynomial  over $\Bbb{F}_q$, but within a single copy of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$, only $n$ of the primitive elements (out of $\phi(q^n-1)$) share the same minimal polynomial. On the other hand, if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are any two copies of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ within $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{F}_q)$, then they are conjugate in the sense that we can find a matrix $A$ such that $AK_1A^{-1}=K_2$ as sets.

Comment: (cont'd) That follows for example from [Skolem-Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) even though it is likely overkill for such a purpose :-)

Comment: @BenGrossmann both are possible (that you've misunderstood or I am misinterpreting something).  If all were conjugate it'd be easy, but they're not, so that's where I was stuck.  I don't see how "not all are conjugate" means my question has a negative answer [but again, my confidence here is low right now].

Comment: Skolem-Noether (and/or friends) imply that if $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of order $q^n-1$, then $A$ is conjugate to some power $B^j$ such that $\gcd(j,q^n-1)$, so the cyclic subgroups generated by $A$ and $B$ respectively are conjugate even though the specific generators need not be.

Comment: Even more precisely, if $T_\alpha$ is a generator of a copy $K$ of $\Bbb{F}_q$, then the only powers $T_{\alpha^j}$ it can be conjugate to have $j=q^\ell$. Those are precisely the elements of $K$ sharing the same minimal polynomial with $T_\alpha$ over $\Bbb{F}_q$ (IOW, its Galois conjugates). On the other hand Skolem-Noether says that every element of the Galois group of $K/\Bbb{F}_q$ can be realized by conjugation within $M_n(\Bbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: @Randall Never mind, per Jyrki's comment we are dealing with a single copy of $\Bbb F_{q^n}$

Comment: [This post might be helpful](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3749791/81360): it classifies the matrices that correspond to elements of the form $T_\alpha$ for (not necessarily primitive) elements $\alpha \in \Bbb F_q^n$.

Comment: Thank you all for helping to clarify my question in the comments [which is actually the point of comments].  I've updated the question with a little bit of context.

Comment: With regards your question now, Jyrki's suggested duplicate is now completely relevant, and not Ben Grossmann's answer. All Singer cycles are conjugate (but in general they aren't rational, so more than one conjugacy classes of *elements* lies inside a given class of *subgroups*, so you take the index of the normalizer of a Singer cycle, the number of generators in a given Singer cycle, multiply the two together, and you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no" if you mean that these matrices correspond to a fixed choice of basis.

I will build a counterexample for the case of $q = 2, n = 3$. Note that all maps of the form $T_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \Bbb F_{2^3}$ commute. Thus, if we find an $\alpha \in \Bbb F_{2^3}$ and a matrix $M \in \Bbb F_2^{3 \times 3}$ such that $M^7 = I$ (since $q^n - 1 = 7$) but $MT_{\alpha} \neq T_\alpha M$, then we have found an $M$ that cannot be realized as a Singer cycle.

Present $\Bbb F_8$ as $\Bbb F_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1 \rangle$. Then relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ of $\Bbb F$, the matrix of $T_{x}$ is given by
$$
[T_x]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&0}.
$$
Because $x$ is a primitive element, $T_x$ has order $7$. This matrix fails to commute with its transpose, $M = ([T_x]_{\mathcal B})^\top$. However, $M$ must have the same order as $T_x$. Thus, $M$ is a matrix of order $q^n - 1$ that does not correspond to a singer cycle (relative to this basis $\mathcal B$).

---

For posterity: we find that
$$
[T_x]_{\mathcal B}([T_x]_{\mathcal B})^\top = \pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&0&0\\
0&0&1},\\
([T_x]_{\mathcal B})^\top[T_x]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&0\\
1&0&0}.
$$

---

It is notable that two matrices of maximal order need not even be **conjugate** to each other. As counterexample to this, consider $[T_x]_{\mathcal B}$ as above and the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1},
$$
which also has order $7$. We can see that these matrices are not conjugate since they have characteristic polynomials $x^3 + x + 1$ and $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ respectively.

---

Regarding the project of counting elements of $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$ of maximal order, I would note the following for the case that $q$ is prime.

It is known that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{q^n - 1}(x)$ [factors into a product of irreducible polynomials of the same degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Cyclotomic_polynomials_over_a_finite_field_and_over_the_p-adic_integers), which (given the existence of primitive elements) must be of degree $n$. Each of the $\varphi(q^n - 1)/n$ factors (that I believe are distinct) are a possible candidate for the characteristic (and minimal) polynomial of a matrix in $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$. In other words matrix with maximal order must be conjugate to the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) associated with one of these polynomials.

With that, the process of selecting a matrix of maximal order can be broken down to selecting a factor of $\Phi_n$, then selecting a matrix that is conjugate to the associated companion matrix.

---

As for counting the elements conjugate to a given companion matrix $C$, the following argument works.

Consider the action of $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$ on itself given by conjugation, i.e. the action $A \cdot X = AXA^{-1}$.

- The matrix $C$ is [non-derogatory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787808/81360), which means that $A$ is in the stabilizer of $C$ if and only if $A = f(C)$ for some polynomial $f$.
- The non-zero matrices of the form $f(C)$ for such a polynomial form a subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$ that is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_{q^n}$. Thus, $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)_C$, the stabilizer subgroup of $C$ has order $q^n - 1$.
- By the orbit stabilizer theorem, the number of distinct elements conjugate to $C$ is given by
  $$
  \frac{|GL_n(\Bbb F_q)|}{|GL_n(\Bbb F_q)_C|} = \frac{(q^n - 1)(q^n - q)\cdots (q^n - q^{n-1})}{q^n - 1} = (q^n - q)\cdots (q^n - q^{n-1}).
  $$

---

Putting the previous two sections together, we have a potential answer for **prime** values of $q$. If we accept the hypothesis that $\Phi_{q^n - 1}$ has no repeating factors, then the total number of distinct matrices in $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$ with order $q^n - 1$ is given by
$$
\frac{\varphi(q^n - 1)}{n} \cdot (q^n - q)\cdots (q^n - q^{n-1}).
$$
Equivalently, the fraction of elements of $GL_n(\Bbb F_q)$ that have maximal order is
$$
\frac{\varphi(q^n - 1)}{n\cdot (q^n - 1)}.
$$

Comment: This seems helpful.  I think you are right in your first sentence:  I think I *do* mean that I am fixing a single basis once and for all.  For clarity, I am trying to count the number of matrices of order $q^n-1$, so having a one-to-one correspondence with Singer cycles would be great.  However, your (fantastic) example is showing that counting the Singer cycles will be an undercount, right?

Comment: @Randall Yes! Typo from my first attempt

Comment: @Randall And yes, the Singer cycles will necessarily be an undercount, as you say

Comment: @Randall You might find my latest edit to be helpful.

Comment: I think we are working under a different definition of a Singer cycle (or reading the question differently). Your matrix $M$ is not conjugate to its transpose, but it is conjugate to the inverse of its transpose, and the powers of the transpose form the multiplicative group of a different copy of $\Bbb{F}_8$. May be I'm missing something because I have never heard Singer cycles being defined *relative to some basis*? At least for the applications I'm familiar with it suffices that a suitable power of the generating matrix map a fixed non-zero vector to any other prescribe non-zero vector?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well we're talking about the *matrix* of a Siger cycle, and the matrix of a linear transformation requires a basis

Comment: Quite, but the Singer property is independent of a choice of basis. As is the property of being a primitive element of a copy of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ inside the matrix algebra. Anyway, I agree with your calculation of the size of the conjugacy class, but I think the answer to the OP's first question is affirmative: every matrix of order $q^n-1$ is gotten as a generator of the multiplicative group of **some** copy of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ inside the matrix algebra. At least that's how I read the first question.

Comment: @Jyrki Ok, I see what you're saying.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding lies with me.  Jyrki's last comment is certainly right.  Since I was hoping to associate primitives with maximal elements in a 1-1 fashion, I had in mind a fixed basis to get a unique Singer cycle per primitive.  But that's not quite how I phrased my question.

Comment: Thanks @BenGrossmann for divining what I was actually trying to ask and giving this very useful answer.  If you have any interest in collaborating on this project offline please let me know here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be any irreducible $\Bbb F_q$-polynomial of degree $n$ and $A$ its Frobenius companion matrix. (Apparently) $A$ generates a Singer cycle. Its centralizer in $M_n(\Bbb F_q)$ is an $n$-dimensional subalgebra (that is $\cong \Bbb F_{q^n}$), so its orbit in $GL_n$ wrt conjugation is of order $(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1}) \approx q^{n^2-n}$, much more than the amount of primitive elements $\varphi(q^n - 1) < q^n$.

On the other hand, if the only thing fixed is the characteristic polynomial, and we can freely choose the basis, then a similarity to the Frobenius form would give a power basis of the field.